# Which Android versions are recommended for PhoneGap development?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, sdk

The PhoneGap installation requires that I install Eclipse, and then use the Android SDK Manager to install the versions of the Android SDK/API. Each of these is a large download, and there is access to versions API 3 through API 21. However, I do not want to install them all and I would like advice on which is a good mix to use when I am not targeting a particular Android version but would like to cover as many devices as possible.

I checked the previous questions and I could not find this specific question from a search. I have noted an important question concerning the Android SDK Build Tools versions, but not the APIs to select.

Do I need to download more than one? Or is the latest (API 21) sufficient for my development work?

If you are aware of previous discussions on this that I have missed in my search I would greatly appreciate being pointed to these.

Comment: why not use native android! just curious!

Comment: I would suggest you download at least the most popular platforms: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html. In my opinion you should test your app on "at least" the following API levels: 14, 19 and 21. Al tough I also test my apps on: 8, 9, 16, 17 and 18 but that's mostly because most of my apps support Android 2.2. And the levels 16, 17 and 18 because these are also widely used. For my largest apps I always test every platform level supported, just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap is currently supporting Cordova 3.6.3 which requires API version 19. That is really the only version you need.